# Opensource UML model to code generation tool with complex workflows

Tags: java, uml, code-generation, modeling

Looking for a free open source UML 2 Java EE app generator - so found two candidates - Andromda (better documentaiton and active forum ) and WitchcraftMDA ( not very well documented but has very powerful workflow generattion & restful services support) .

Anyone has any experience with these tools or something else that will help us focus on solving business problems rather than mundante tasks like  screens, validation , i18n , persistence etc ...

We need forks , joins, loops etc - the whole JBPM / BPMN language set.

Answer (score 0):

AndroMDA is generating java code from a a structural model coming from class diagrams. The generated code is using uml tags represented as stereotypes in the class diagram. You can not generated code from JBPM or BPMN.